# Is there a package (like showlabels) for amsrefs?

Tags: amsrefs, showlabels

I'd like `amsrefs` to print (in the bibliography, not with the actual citations, e.g. in the margin) the label used in the `\bib` and `\cite` commands (i.e., the first argument to `\bib`).  I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\origbib=\bib
\def\bib#1#2#3{\llap{#1\qquad}\origbib{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

This: \cite{a} and that: \cite{b} are important papers.

\vspace{6\baselineskip}\lipsum[1-4] % to get a page break between papers in the bibliography

\begin{biblist}
  \bib{a}{article}{
    author={Someone},
    title={A title},
  }
  \bib{b}{article}{
    author={Another one},
    title={Another title},
  }
\end{biblist}

\end{document}
```

but it doesn't work very well (`\llap` is issued in vertical mode, and adding `\leavevmode` before causes some errors I don't have enough motivation to investigate due to the deadline... :-/).  Adding `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` after the `\llap` helps a bit, but still the label for the *first* entry on a page gets printed on the previous page.  I can live with this, but I'm also wondering whether there's a better (also, more elegant) solution.

Comment: I expect you can use showlabels, but it needs a MWE

Comment: You probably should explain more clearly what you mean as it's not really clear. A MWE would help and save people from wasting their time.

Comment: I know, I know, people!!!  One comment is enough!  It's 22:30 here, I have a deadline, and I forgot about a MWE... ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `showlabels` seems to know nothing about amsrefs.

Comment: @mbork have faith

Comment: I also clarified the problem (though the code shows what I mean anyway, I hope;)...)

Comment: I think that David means the `showkeys` package, which he coauthored. In any case this seems to work. (Alternatively you can use `todonotes` as per my deleted answer:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

works for me?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\begin{document}

This: \cite{a} and that: \cite{b} are important papers.

\vspace{6\baselineskip}\lipsum[1-4] % to get a page break between papers in the bibliography

\begin{biblist}
  \bib{a}{article}{
    author={Someone},
    title={A title},
  }
  \bib{b}{article}{
    author={Another one},
    title={Another title},
  }
\end{biblist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well yes, the labels do print in the margin next to the bib items, but unless it's just my old eyes, they are also (almost) overprinting the references where cited.  (they'll go away in the final copy, but ...)

Comment: @barbarabeeton almost is good:-) (the main idea is not to affect the typesetting of the existing text so by design they are somewhat squeezed in)

Comment: Well, my fault - I mixed the names of `showlabels` and `showkeys`...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way to use `showlabels` for this case is something like

```
\usepackage{showlabels}
\showlabels{bib}
```

The result isn't exactly as you describe, but does indicate the `\bib` label with a `{a}` in the margin.  The showlabels package tries quite hard to avoid spacing changes, so if a spacing change does appear in this case, that may be a showlabels bug.

Comment: Indeed, there *were* some spacing changes.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ooops: then can you illustrate here a minimal example which illustrates the spacing change? I should be able to fix that. Add it here, or there's an issues list [at bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/showlabels/issues) (oops, I see I'm a little behind – this might prompt me to do a catch-up)

Comment: I'll try, though that might be tough - my example is a not-so-small document with a custom class...